# Subgradient everywhere terminology

Tags: convex-analysis, subgradient, non-smooth-analysis

Suppose I have a function $h$ and a function $f$. The function $f$ is non-differentiable and thus, does not have a gradient. However, the function $h$ belongs to the subgradient of $f$ at every $x$, i.e., $h(x) \in \partial f(x)$ for all $x$.

Does this function $h$ has a name? Would it be appropriate to call it simply a "subgradient" of $f$ without specifying at which $x$ it a subgradient?

Comment: I've found the terms to be a bit of a muddle when I've come across them in the literature: "subgradient", "subderivative" and "subdifferential" tend to be used interchangeably. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative) suggests that the *subdifferential* is the **set** $\partial f(x)$, while its elements are *subgradients*.

Comment: The subdifferential at $x_0$ is defined to be the set of all subgradients at $x_0$. People can be very casual about usage but this definition is clear. I'm wondering if there is a particular name for a function which belongs to the subdifferential at every point.

Comment: Oh! In that case, I doubt it has a special name, since that is sufficient to conclude $f$ is affine (assuming $f$ has full domain). You could call it the "linear part" of $f$. :)

Comment: Good point. I was just curious if there is some concept I am unaware of. I current say "h is a subgradient of f at every x", but this feels clunky.

Comment: @TheoBendit: I do not see why $f$ should be affine. You can take, e.g. $f(x) = |x|$ and $h$ be the signum-function (with $h(0) = 0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an $h$ is called a *selection* of the subdifferential.

Given a set-valued function $A \colon X \rightrightarrows Y$, a function $a \colon X \to Y$ is a selection of $A$, if
$$
a(x) \in A(x) \qquad\forall x \in X.$$

Typical usages are "measurable selections" and "continuous selections".

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I am looking for. Is there a canonical reference for this? I'd like to cite a formal definition, if possible.

Comment: Nevermind, I suppose the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choice_function give sufficient background.